# Namenode file division into blocks

Tags: hdfs, hadoop2

I am aware that a file is split into blocks by name node while stored into HDFS . But when the file is divided , there is chance that a block will contain a part of the line . Is my understanding correct ? So if i will have any map operation that needs to read each line then i will miss some part of a line to process by mapper .

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @RojoSam's answer, `SPLIT_SLOP` parameter is used by RecordReader to read data of a single file from other blocks. `SPLIT_SLOP` gives hadoop job to read % of data from remote host if data is not completely available at single datanode.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, It is posible that a line be splitted in two blocks. The Reader used by the mapper at the end of the block read the first line for the next block and process it. If it isn't the first block, the reader always skip the first line. At least for text files. Other formats work different.

You won't miss any part of a line